# Необходимо быстро удалить дубликаты по нескольким полям из таблицы

Tags: sql, vb.net

Есть таблица `50000+` строк и `60+` столбцов.

Необходимо удалить строки, в которых совпадают 15 определенных полей (`field_11...field_25`) из 60-ти.

Удаление дубликатов по первым двум полям, оставляя только более новые записи реализовывал так:

```
Dim c As New OleDbCommand
        c.Connection = conn
        c.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM myBase AS t1 WHERE Exists (SELECT * FROM myBase AS t2 WHERE t1.field_2=t2.field_2 and t1.Код<t2.Код)"
        c.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Код выше прекрасно и быстро работает, но вот для большого количества текстовых полей, по которым происходит сравнение, оказался неприменим.

Каким образом следует сформировать запрос?

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE 
FROM myBase 
WHERE id NOT IN (  SELECT MIN(id)
                   FROM myBase 
                   GROUP BY field1, field2, ... , field15
                )
```

Впрочем, вряд ли это будет быстро - при группировке по 15 текстовым полям-то...

Comment: К сожалению, да, не справляется запрос.

Comment: Проблема - именно в подзапросе. Даже если убрать удаляющую обвязку, и просто попытаться слить найденные ID во временную таблицу - и то, я думаю, серверу поплохеет... Но не я придумал отбирать дубликаты ТАК... можно попробовать сконкатенировать набор полей сравнения и получить его хэш, и дальше работать с ним (конечно, при совпадении хэша выполнять полное сравнение).

Comment: В этом ключе я не подумал, спасибо, мне кажется вполне рабочий вариант